# Easier way to provide image credit/attribution

Tags: feature-request, images

This is similar to [this Meta Stack Overflow question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/115911/191347), but I think it probably becomes more of an issue on UX.SE where questions naturally tend to benefit from a visual/graphical response.

While I certainly appreciate the speed, stability and archival benefits of StackExchange rehosting images on Imgur, I always feel a little uncomfortable about using images sourced from the Internet without clear attribution given.

At the moment I generally provide attribution on the next line in italics, but it's hard to style appropriately (and doesn't encourage other users to provide similar attribution themselves).

Could we reasonably add a field to the Image Upload popup that automatically inserts a (nicely-styled) attribution credit into the content when supplied?

Comment: Seems like this would require at least two fields (link + attribution text) so I'm not sure adding it to the upload form every time is ideal

Comment: @BenBrocka It could work similarly to the current alt tag implementation (inserted into the markdown for editing), or perhaps behave like Facebook where you provide a link and it uses the link's HTML title as the default link text?